# Why is there a problematic sort in my SQL Server delete query plan?

Tags: sql-server

I have a very large table (150m+ rows) in SQL Server 2012 (web edition) that has no clustered index and one non-clustered index.

When I run this delete statement:

```
DELETE TOP(500000) 
FROM pick 
WHERE tournament_id < 157
```

(column name is in the non-clustered index), the execution plan produced by SQL Server looks like this:

[image: query plan]

The sort step looks problematic - it takes up 45% of the cost, and it is causing an alert saying "operator used tempdb to spill data during execution." The query is taking several minutes to run, and I feel like it should be quicker.

Two questions:

1. Why is there a sort step in the plan?
2. Any ideas how to overcome the spill? The server has 64gb of RAM and tempdb is sized at 8x 4gb data files.

I can definitely revisit the indexing strategy on this table if that might help.

Hope this all makes sense - thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: The sort is there because you have a `TOP` clause - SQL Server needs to determine *which* rows to delete, even if you can't specify via an explicit `ORDER BY`. Why don't you have a clustered index? How many rows have that `tournament_id` value, out of how many rows total? Is the non-clustered index on a single column? Essentially to get a better plan (and more importantly better performance) you need to either break the delete into smaller chunks or add more selective index columns (or additional indexes) to allow it to better choose the rows to delete (of course more index = more work).

Comment: I'm also not sure if you have a specific reason to not have a clustered index. Heaps definitely have their upsides in certain scenarios, but these scenarios are not common IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand It seems that without an ORDER BY, SQL Server could pick *any* "TOP N" results ..

Comment: Is there an index on `tournament_id`? It seems like, if there *were* and index, the planner should simply be able to walk-the-index and prune at the N limit (because of lack of further ordering) - and I would imagine that the deleted selected rows were in order of that index.

Comment: @user2864740 It still has to pick them. Just like when it returns rows in a SELECT without ORDER BY, it still has to present them in SOME order.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Since it can pick *any* then it doesn't need to sort - it can just stop after N results have been found, no? (I do not deal with heap tables, so I could be completely off with what SQL server does in this case.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for such a quick response. Around 70% of the rows have tournament_id < 157. And there is no clustered index purely for legacy reasons - it's an ancient table that has been in constant use over many years. It's a table that has a lot of drip-feed single row inserts, and regular bulk updates that can touch a few hundred thousand rows at a time. The updates are always problematic (slow) - would a clustered index potentially help?

Comment: @user2864740 currently tournament_id is one of 4 columns in the non-clustered index. Would an index with tournament_id alone be better in this scenario? (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: Can you post the XML for the actual execution plan?

Comment: @AndyW `tournament_id` must be the *first* (and possibly only) column in an index for it to be used in the given query (indexes cover left-to-right). I'm not sure if being the *only* column in the index would help.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks. tournament_id is the first column in the index, but there are 3 others as well. So having an index with only tournament_id sounds like the way to go - as well as introducing a clustered index by the sounds of it.

Comment: @AndyW Definitely play around and see what the query plans show. Also, don't forget to update the statistics.

Comment: I've set up a test table and reproduced it. It does seem unnecessary as they are coming out of the index seek in order of `key,rid` but the seek only outputs the rid and then outputs the key from the delete operator and sorts it back into `key,rid` order.

Comment: Can also confirm that the sort is still there if you remove `TOP`

Comment: @MartinSmith since writing I've started fiddling with the indexes and no longer have that query plan to hand so getting the xml will be tricky (though I'm no expert at this stuff). Great that you could reproduce it though - gives me some comfort! Fiddling with the indexes sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @MartinSmith there is no sort if I remove the TOP. The trick looks to be to batch the delete in different ways.

Comment: @AndyW - [This was my test table structure and plan](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lmv4M.png). Seems to be a cost based "optimisation" that isn't actually an optimisation. If it expects few rows then the sort doesn't appear. e.g. `DELETE TOP (10) FROM pick` doesn't show it.

Comment: @MartinSmith great - I can see the sort there. I've now established that (with my new non-clustered index on tournament_id in place), this will cause a sort: "delete from pick where tournament_id < 157" and this will not: "delete from pick where tournament_id = 117". So it looks like the < operator is introducing the sort.

Comment: @AndyW - How many delete operators do you see in the new plan? One or Two? Maybe the sort is always present if it is a [wide plan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/07/27/680518.aspx). Still don't see why it is needed though as there is no intermediate operation after the initial seek that would disorder the rows anyway.

Comment: Ah no reproed with the `=` seek and a large number of rows and a wide plan that the sort goes as well. I suppose it keeps track that the rid will be in order and that it only affects one key so the sort would be redundant in that case.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that there seems to be no good reason for a sort here.

I don't think it is needed for Halloween protection as it doesn't show up in the `= 157` version of the plan.

Also the sort operation is sorting in order of `Key Asc, Bmk ASC` (presumably to get them ordered sequentially in index order) but this is the order the forward index seek on the very same index is returning the rows in anyway.

One way of removing it would be to obfuscate the `TOP` to get a narrow (per row) rather than a wide (per index) plan.

```
DECLARE @N INT = 500000

DELETE TOP(@N) 
FROM pick
WHERE  tournament_id < 157 
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@N=1))
```

[image]

You'd need to test to see if this actually improved things or not.

Answer (score 3):

I would try smaller chunks and a more selective WHERE clause, as well as a way to force SQL Server to pick the TOP rows in an order you specify:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TOP (10000) tournament_id
  FROM dbo.pick
  WHERE tournament_id < 157 -- AND some other where clause perhaps?
  ORDER BY tournament_id -- , AND some other ordering column
)
DELETE x;
```

More selective could also mean deleting tournament_id < 20, then tournament_id < 40, etc. etc. instead of picking 500000 random rows from 1-157. Typically it's better for your system overall (both in terms of blocking impact, lock escalations etc., as well as impact to the log) to perform a series of small transactions rather than one large one. I blogged about this here: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

The sort may still be present in these cases (particularly if it is for Hallowe'en protection or something to do with the RID), but it may be far less problematic at a smaller scale (please don't go just based on that estimated cost % number, because often those numbers are garbage). So first I would really consider adding a clustered index. Without more requirements I don't have an explicit suggestion for you, but it could be as simple as a clustered index only on tournament_id (depending on how many potential rows you have per id) or adding an IDENTITY column which you could potentially use to help determine rows to delete in the future.

Comment: Thanks - all very helpful. In terms of a clustered index, here's a bit more background. The table has several columns that are all important in terms of assorted different queries that hit it - tournament_id, player_id, game_id, pool_id. Writes are very regular, with single records being written. Big, heavy updates are done when sports matches end (it's a fantasy game). An update hits a specific tournament_id, player_id, game_id, pool_id combination. My instinct is to add an identity column and make that the clustered index - any further thoughts?

Comment: @AndyW sounds like a reasonable first go. Really not possible with the given information to say "your best clustered index would be _____."

Answer (score 2):

I'ld the following steps:

1. Create an clusterd index on the column tournament_id
2. Update Statistics for your database
3. run your query again

From my experience this should give some seconds.

In addition I'll do a more detailed query to your table, if possible.

Version 1 (with date format dd/mm/yyyy):

```
;WITH To_Delete
(
SELECT tournament_id
FROM dbo.pick
WHERE tournmanet_id < 157
AND date like '01/%/2013' -- if available, Need to be customized
AND date like '03/%/2013' -- if available, Need to be customized
)
DELETE X;
```

Verion 2 (with `month` function, no matter which format your date have):

```
;WITH To_Delete
(
SELECT tournament_id
FROM dbo.pick
WHERE tournmanet_id < 157
AND month(date) = 1
AND month(date) < 3
)
DELETE X;
```

Comment: do you think it is wise to filter out a month like this? How about using the `month` function? Remember, other cultures have a different date formats.

Comment: that is correct, but i'ld like to give an example and to be honest now one should copy paste and scriplet from here without reconsidering it or customize it for his or her requirenments

Comment: Well, if you're aware of that, why don't you just edit your post and make it copy & pastable? Wouldn't be much of a problem, would it?

Comment: just added a snippet with `month` function, thanks for the hint alzaimar